# How can I unbind an onClick event handler until it's needed?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an issue with a game in JavaScript.

My game lives inside a canvas, and I make large use of function almost like:

```
document.onmousemove = function(event) {

    var mouseX = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    //mouse position is relative to player position
    mouseX -= CANVAS_WIDTH/2;
    mouseY -= CANVAS_HEIGHT/2;

    player.aimAngle = Math.atan2(mouseY, mouseX) / Math.PI * 180;
}

document.onclick = function(event) {

 if(player.canAttack && player.distance >= 80) {        //not for sword attack
     performAttack(player);
     player.canAttack = false;
 }

 if(player.distance < 80)
     performAttack(player);


 event.preventDefault();
}
```

But before dynamically creating the canvas I have a login form. When I click with mouse to select those form I got in console the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canAttack' of undefined . That's because I have not called yet the Player() constructor, so canAttack doesn't exists and for the onMouseMove canvas doesn't exist yet.

How do I "disable" or unbind the document.onclick and document.onmousemove?
If they were done with addEventListener I would disable them with removeEventListener. How could I do with document.onclick instead?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you bind the document.onClick only after creating the Player ?

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: // Attach an event handler to <div>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);

// Remove the event handler from <div>
document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);

Comment: bind the event to the canvas instead of binding it to the document

Comment: The snippet in insufficent to provide a complete answer, what I can say is that binding click on the document itself is a bit extreme measure. Additionaly you have to wait after initialization before applying such events.

Comment: Late binding is not going to guarantee the **Player** exists each time the document is clicked. Check if the `Player` exists and exit if it doesn't. When using objects not passed in through parameters those objects could be changed at any time by anything in your code, hence you should **always** check them before using them.

Comment: thanks everyone, I edited my snippet

Comment: @Condo as I said, check the object, i.e: `if(!player){return;}` or similar as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Nope, I quickly solved with your solution. So the "best" way to do that would be to attach a eventListener to the canvas instead of attacching it to the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

Try following when have to remove listener

```
function noop(){}

document.onclick = noop // when have to remove click binding
```